# google検索でreCAPTCHAの画像のフェードアウト速度が変化するのには技術的な理由がありますか

Tags: security, google-search, recaptcha

利用する図書館ではgoogleを利用しており、そこで検索するとreCAPTCHAが出てきます。

自宅ではチェックマークを押して画像を数回選ぶだけで済むのですが、図書館では画像が消えたり出てきたりするのが非常にゆっくりで、画像をクリックするのを5分ほど繰り返さないと先に進めませんでした。

reCAPTCHAでは正しい画像がクリックされたかで人間かロボットかを見分けると理解してますが、
それならなぜ画像のフェードアウト・インの速さに違いがあるのでしょうか？
何か技術的な理由がありますか？

Answer (score 3):

最新の reCAPTCHA では人間と判断されている間は単にチェックを入れるだけで済むはずですが、ボットの疑い度合いが高まるにつれて選択すべき数が増えたり、質問のように画像の表示にウェイト(待ち時間)が設定されたりするようです。

- 「私はボットではありません」にチェックを入れるだけ
- 指定のオブジェクト(の固まり=隣り合うマス)を選択する
- 指定のオブジェクトを選択する
- 指定のオブジェクトが表示されなくなるまで選択を繰り返す
- 指定のオブジェクトが表示されなくなるまで選択を繰り返す (画像が表示されるまでウェイトあり)

---

どんな時にボットと疑われる度合いが高くなるかと言うと、一つは「判断が早すぎる」時。待ち時間が発生するのも、その対策としてでしょう。ある程度質問のパターンは決まっているので、人間でも短時間で選択できてしまうケースがあります。

もう一つは「大量のリクエストがあった時」。図書館と言う場所柄、あなたが操作しているPC以外にも検索用の端末が複数設置されているのではないでしょうか。

それらの端末が外部ネットワークに対して一つのグローバルIPでアクセスしている場合には、見かけ上大量の reCAPTCHA が呼び出されることになり、ボットの疑いが強くなってしまい結果として複雑な選択を迫られている可能性があります。

参考:
[Why is reCAPTCHA image fade in/out so slow? - Super User](https://superuser.com/q/1337801)